# How can I edit a website application settings in Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have uploaded my website to Azure. Now, I want to change an application setting value. How can I do that? Will I have to change it locally and then republish the whole site?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, any changes made to files on azure are temporary, and will go back to original state once azure app pool recycles. you have to make the app settings related changes locally and republish the website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using app settings, or connection strings in your web.config you'll see them in the Azure Website -> Configure -> App Settings section.

```
<app settings>
    <add key="Setting" value="SomeVal"/>
</app settings>
```

The "Setting" key would then appear in Azure and you can edit it from there. It will survive app pool restarts.

[image: Azure App Settings]

In the event you aren't using app settings / connection strings you'll have to republish to change other web.config settings.